# Insert data into mysql tables using ansible

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, ansible

There should be some decent way to work with mysql databases using ansible like inserting data into tables or any command to run on mysql db.

I know there are modules to create db, manage replications, user and variables:

- `mysql_db` - Add or remove MySQL databases from a remote host.
- `mysql_replication` (E) - Manage MySQL replication
- `mysql_user` - Adds or removes a user from a MySQL database.
- `mysql_variables` - Manage MySQL global variables

My use case scenario is, I've installed `mysql-server` on ubuntu and created the database successfully and now I have to insert data into the tables and wondering if there is a way to achieve it via ansible.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

**Solution 1:**

I think you missed import functionality of `mysql_db` module. You can load both schema and data with it using `import` as parameter to state and giving it a file to load in `target`

Example from Ansible docs:

```
# Copy database dump file to remote host and restore it to database 'my_db'
- copy: src=dump.sql.bz2 dest=/tmp
- mysql_db: name=my_db state=import target=/tmp/dump.sql.bz2
```

**Solution 2:**

If mysql_db does not give you all options that you need and flexibility you can just use `mysql` program in combination with `shell`.

```
- name: Import DB 
  shell: mysql db_name < dump.sql
```

Above loads `dump.sql` file into database `db_name`. See `mysql` program manual for more options: [man mysql](http://linux.die.net/man/1/mysql)

**Solution 3:**

`mysqlimport` utility with `command` module:

```
- name: Import DB 
  command: mysqlimport [options] db_name textfile1 [textfile2 ...]
```

See: [mysqlimport docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqlimport.html)

Comment: Thanks both! appreciate your response! import parameter in mysql_db works well. I also have to update existing .sql in our deployments so working on that now. Thanks again:)

Comment: There are some handy tips in the following thread to help avoid importing the same database each time you run a playbook: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ansible-project/XrQ08TdtcRk/I4s7rF7GkyMJ

Answer (score 7):

You can use [mysql_db](http://docs.ansible.com/mysql_db_module.html) module. Its `state:` parameter has values of `present`, `absent`, `dump`, **`import`**. If it is set to `import`, then you can use `target:` parameter to indicate location, on the remote host, of the dump file to read from. Uncompressed SQL files (.sql) as well as bzip2 (.bz2) and gzip (.gz) compressed files are supported.

```
# Copy database dump file to remote host and restore it to database 'my_db'
- copy: src=dump.sql.bz2 dest=/tmp
- mysql_db: name=my_db state=import target=/tmp/dump.sql.bz2
```

Comment: Danger: This overwrites any existing database (if the import sql has drops).  See https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/ansible-project/XrQ08TdtcRk/I4s7rF7GkyMJ