# Escape string value for mysql insert/update request in ansible

Tags: mysql, insert, ansible, escaping

I need to create ansible task which inserts a string value into database. The problem is that the string value may contain all sorts of spaces, quotes, etc.

I am going to do approximately this:

```
- name: Insert record
  command: mysql db_name -e "INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES ('{{ the_value }}');"
```

`the_value` variable contains the string, but as I mentioned there are all sorts of spaces and quotes in it. So, it should be escaped.

The standard ansible `quote` filter probably is not appropriate here, because it escapes strings to be used in shell commands, but I do not use shell.

There is somewhat similar question here: [Insert data into mysql tables using ansible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28188508) , but it doesn't help to solve the escaping problem.

Comment: Are you delcaring `the_value` in an `ansible-playbook` call?  If so, can you post that call with an abbreviated version of the space-laden value?

Comment: @WEBjuju I am new to ansible, so I do not know exactly how `the_value` variable will get it's value. It's value will be read from a file - which is supposed to contain some config. Just need to save the whole contents of this file into database.

Answer (score 0):

I combined the answers from https://stackoverflow.com/a/6478616/2897386 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/60461596/2897386 , to produce this code:

```yaml
- name: "MySQL escape the_value"
  set_fact:
    the_value: "{{ the_value | regex_replace(item.0, item.1) }}"
  loop:
    - ["\\\\", '\\\\']
    - ["\u0000", '\\0']
    - ["'", "\\'"]
    - ["\"", '\\"']
    - ["\b", '\\b']
    - ["\n", '\\n']
    - ["\r", '\\r']
    - ["\t", '\\t']
    - ["\u001A", '\\Z']
```

Answer (score -1):

I failed to find an appropriate filter, so I used slightly different approach. First I save data to a file on a host where database is running, and after that I use `LOAD_FILE` sql function.

Something like this:

```
- name: Insert record
  command: mysql db_name -e "INSERT INTO table(column) VALUES (LOAD_FILE('{{ path_to_data_file }}'));"
```

Some notes.

- the `LOAD_FILE` function is probably `mysql`-specific so you might have to use different function/syntax for different databases
- the file should be saved on the host the database is runnig (which may be different from the remote host of this task)
- to save data to remote file you can use `copy` module with `content` parameter.