# replace multiple patterns with multiple values in ansible

Tags: python, json, regex, ansible

I am using `regex_replace` filter in ansible. i can make it work, but its really cumbersome .
This is how i am doing

```
- set_fact:
    variable: "{{ value | regex_replace("84","89") | regex_replace("76","78") | regex_replace("45","23"}}"
```

Is there a way, i can pipe regex_replace one time and replace multiple patterns with multiple values.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Q: ***"Can I pipe regex_replace one time and replace multiple patterns with multiple values?"***

A: No. It's not possible. But, you can do it in a loop. For example,

```yaml
  vars:

    my_var: ABCDEFGH

  tasks:

    - set_fact:
        my_var: "{{ my_var|regex_replace(item.regex, item.replace) }}"
      loop:
        - {regex: 'A', replace: '1'}
        - {regex: 'C', replace: '3'}
        - {regex: 'E', replace: '5'}
    - debug:
        var: my_var
```

gives

```yaml
    my_var: 1B3D5FGH
```

You can minimize the code. For example, the task below gives the same result

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_var: "{{ my_var|regex_replace(item.0, item.1) }}"
      loop:
        - ['A', '1']
        - ['C', '3']
        - ['E', '5']
```

---

Q: ***"Can we make this not take the replaced value as an input for the next loop item?"***

A: Yes. We can. The better structure in this case is a dictionary. For example,

```yaml
    my_var: AB1
    regrep:
      'A': '1'
      '1': 'C'
```

The expected result is '1BC'. We don't want the first character replaced with 'C'. The Jinja expression below gives what you want

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        my_var: |
          {% for x in  my_var %}
          {% if x in regrep %}
          {{ regrep[x] }}
          {%- else %}
          {{ x }}
          {%- endif %}
          {%- endfor %}
```

Comment: Can we somehow make this not take the replaced value of a letter as an input for next loop item? i.e. if I replaced `A -> 1` and the input string was AB then it'll give me 1B, but IF input string was AB and loop had A->1 and 1->C pattern, then, `how can we make sure this operation won't change` it to `CB`. As Input string was not 1B. It seems likes it, these loop patterns are using the DYNAMIC value of variable for next loop pattern regex replace.

Comment: Yes. We can. I added an example.